# Set priority on variables in Bash

Tags: bash

I've few variables (the number of variables is dynamic) in csv format as below:-

```
var1,var2,var3...
```

I need to prioritize the variables in below manner

```
priority,variable
1,var1
2,var2
3,var3
......
```

and then compare the priority of variables using [IF Statement]

So how do I add priority/weight to each of the variables ?

Comment: And your quesition is...?

Comment: @Matthias, Thnx for reminding.. I get lost a lot these days !

Comment: Is the priority the same as the digits in the name, or is the priority depending on the order in the csv file?

Comment: @glennjackman, priority depends on the order of variable in csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the lines of your file, use `IFS` and `read -a` to read the values into an array. Then, it's simple enough to iterate over the array and assign a priority based on the index.

```
echo "priority,variable"

while IFS=, read -a vars; do
    for idx in "${!vars[@]}"; do
        echo "$((idx+1)),${vars[idx]}"
    done
done << END
a,b,c,d,e,f
END
```

```
priority,variable
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
6,f
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I resolved the issue using array and didn't had to use any priority as well